# URL rewriting error

Tags: php, .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I want to get parameter from http://domain.com/class/9th-class
I am using 
`RewriteRule ^class/(.*)/?$ classes_list.php?get_page=$1 [NC,QSA]` 
to get `get_page` GET parameter. but it is changing my URL to `http://domain.com/class/9th-class?get_page=9th-class` i dont want to change URL but i want to get the url parameter. If u have any solution please let me know. my whole .htaccess is

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} page_id [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [F]

RewriteRule ^signup/?$ signup.php [NC,QSA]
RewriteRule ^signin/?$ signin.php [NC,QSA]
RewriteRule ^contactus/?$ contactus.php [NC,QSA]

RewriteRule ^freelectures/?$ free_lectures.php [NC,QSA]
RewriteRule ^videos/(.*)/?$ video_details.php?get_page=$1 [NC,QSA]
RewriteRule ^class/(.*)/?$ classes_list.php?get_page=$1 [NC,QSA]

RewriteRule ^course/(.*)/?$ course_details.php?get_page=$1 [NC,QSA]

RewriteRule ^mcqs/(.*)/?$ mcqs_list.php?get_page=$1 [NC,QSA]


RewriteRule ^404/?$ 404.php [NC,QSA]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* /404 [L]

AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/plain
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xhtml+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/rss+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript


RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} libwww-perl.* 
RewriteRule .* ? [F,L]

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s on(s)|offs()
RewriteRule ^ http%1://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,L,R]

<IfModule mod_expires.c>
    ExpiresActive on
# Default directive
ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 month"
 # My favicon
ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access plus 1 year"
    ExpiresByType image/jpg "access plus 1 year"
    ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 1 year"
    ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 1 year"
    ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 1 year"
    # CSS
ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 1 year"
# Javascript
ExpiresByType application/javascript "access plus 1 year"
</IfModule>
<ifModule mod_gzip.c>
  mod_gzip_on Yes
  mod_gzip_dechunk Yes
  mod_gzip_item_include file .(html?|txt|css|js|php|pl)$
  mod_gzip_item_include handler ^cgi-script$
  mod_gzip_item_include mime ^text/.*
  mod_gzip_item_include mime ^application/x-javascript.*
  mod_gzip_item_exclude mime ^image/.*
  mod_gzip_item_exclude rspheader ^Content-Encoding:.*gzip.*
</ifModule>
```

Comment: I would expect your initial statement to be actually wrong. I dare say your URL does not get rewritten to `http://domain.com/class/9th-class?get_page=9th-class` but a `https` URL. Since you do not terminate your rewrite process after handling the "class" rewrite rule you go on checking for https and redirect to it. That always is an external redirection. Since you reassemble the URL in that rule you get the original requested URL as a result again (not the rewriteen one) plus the appended get argument, since `QSA` is the default.

Comment: Yes i rewrite to https too. but for URL I want to get get_page on page level. it is working but it also change URL to `http://domain.com/class/9th-class?get_page=9th-class` too

Comment: Yes, and I explained in my last comment _why_ it does that.

Comment: On a short glance I'd say you have to change the order: _first_ do the external redirection to `https` and the "www host name". Those redirections obviously have to change the visible URL. Then, with the returning request you _then_ do the internal rewriting.

Comment: Please write in answer, I'll rate up your answer. and also please rate up my question too :) this worked.

Comment: I did not give a definite answer, but just a hint, based on my expression. I did not test that which is why I do not write an answer, but a comment.

Comment: Your hint worked. :) Thanks mate.